# Unable to restart node server after making a change

Tags: node.js

Some code changes I made to our test server are not taking effect. I am trying to make sure the node server was properly restarted after the change. Following are the processes with name "node" showing as running -

```
[root@ip-10-30-30-4 lib]# ps -aux | grep node
root     18643  0.0  0.7 916304 26544 ?        Ssl  17:22   0:00 /usr/bin/node /usr/lib/node_modules/forever/bin/monitor app.js
root     21479  0.0  1.7 980380 62528 ?        Sl   19:31   0:00 /root/.nvm/v7.2.1/bin/node /usr/local/mvc/MVC2.0/app.js
root     21491  0.0  2.1 972432 78220 ?        Sl   19:31   0:00 /usr/bin/node /usr/local/mvc/MVC2.0/app.js
root     21858  0.0  0.0 112652   960 pts/1    S+   19:48   0:00 grep --color=auto node
root     22515  0.0  0.8 920548 31008 ?        Ssl  Nov03   0:00 /root/.nvm/v7.2.1/bin/node /usr/lib/node_modules/forever/bin/monitor app.js
```

I tried killing the node processes running app.js (with IDs 21479 and 21491), excluding the PIDs 18643 and 22515. It seems to be monitoring script which restarts the server as soon as it stops. Here are its contents -

```
var fs = require('fs'),
    path = require('path'),
    forever = require(path.resolve(__dirname, '..', 'lib', 'forever')),
    started;

//
// ### @function (file, pid)
// #### @file {string} Location of the pid file.
// #### @pid {number} pid to write to disk.
// Write the pidFile to disk for later use
//
function writePid(file, pid) {
  fs.writeFileSync(file, pid, 'utf8');
}

//
// ### @function start (options)
// #### @options {Object} Options for the `forever.Monitor` instance.
// Starts the child process and disconnects from the IPC channel.
//
function start(options) {
  var script = process.argv[2],
      monitor = new forever.Monitor(script, options);

  forever.logEvents(monitor);
  monitor.start();

  monitor.on('start', function () {
    //
    // This starts an nssocket server, which the forever CLI uses to
    // communicate with this monitor process after it's detached.
    // Without this, `forever list` won't show the process, even though it
    // would still be running in the background unaffected.
    //
    forever.startServer(monitor);

    //
    // Disconnect the IPC channel, letting this monitor's parent process know
    // that the child has started successfully.
    //
    process.disconnect();

    //
```

As soon as I kill the process, with the following command -

```
kill <PID>
```

I still see the same processes with new process IDs, which confirms that the processes were restarted. However, the changes are still not reflecting. Should I kill the ones with PIDs 18643 and 22515 as well? I am not sure how was it run actually.

Comment: `Forever` is not a monitor, it's a script that runs and then re-runs the same script on crash/failure. From what I can see you are running multiple instances of the same server(yes, you should kill all related processes) and if you start with `forever` you don't need another instance. Also, don't run node as root.

Comment: I was able to kill all node processes using `pkill node` and then the change reflected.